# Realm query sum of property

Tags: ios, database, swift, realm

I'm using RealmSwift and I have a realm object called `Book`

```
Book
=====
title: String
pageCount: Int
```

when the app starts I get all the books using:

```
allBooks = realm.objects(Book)
```

a Book has a realm property called `pageCount`

I'm trying to understand how can I get the total pages count for all the books?

So if I have book A with 3 pages, book B with 11 pages and book C with 0 page the total count will be 3+11+0 = 14

I prefer doing it with a query and not iterate through all the books

Answer (score 14):

You can get the total number of pages for all your book objects as follows:

```
let totalPages: Int = realm.objects(Book).sum("pageCount")
```

Comment: @brandonscript I think it's pretty explicit how it solves OP's question? He literally asked "How can I get the total pages count for all `Book`s, considering each `Book` object has a `pageCount` property?".

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for .sum()?

Comment: @teotwaki OLD comment ;) post has been updated since.

Comment: @Jeff You can find the documentation here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.0.2/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift7Results3sumuRd__S_11AddableTyperFT10ofPropertySS_qd__

Comment: @brandonscript Apologies, didn't see the date.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4+:**

```
let totalPages: Int = realm.objects(Book.self).sum(ofProperty: "pageCount")
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5+, SwiftUI

```
let totalPages = realm.objects(Book.self).sum(of: \.pageCount)
```